# MySQL JSON_SET destroyes my unicode encoded umlauts

Tags: mysql, json

MySQL (Version 8.0.26) JSON_SET reformats my JSON string and removes the unicode encoding of (german) umlauts. I don't understand why.

In detail:

I have a created a MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE test_t (
    test_c TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

... and inserted a JSON string (created by PHP json_encode())

```
INSERT INTO test_t(test_c) VALUES ('{"a":"M\\u00fcller","b":"foo"}')
```

The result is this

```
SELECT * FROM test_t => {"a":"M\u00fcller","b":"foo"}
```

If I update the "b" in the JSON with this statement

```
UPDATE test_t SET test_c = JSON_SET(test_c, "$.b", "bar")
```

MySQL is modifying the JSON, removing my unicode encoded umlaut resulting in this

```
SELECT * FROM test_t => {"a": "Müller", "b": "bar"}
```

AFAIK this is not longer a valid JSON and in deed cannot longer processed by PHP json_decode()

Is this a bug? Is this a feature?
What can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I tested json_decode() and it works fine. Using PHP 8.1.3 on my computer. What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: For what it's worth, both encodings should be identical unless you aren't really using UTF-8. Encoding as `\u` entity makes the string ASCII-compatible for such cases. (No, I don't know if MySQL allows to customise this).

Comment: @BillKarwin I use 7.4.28 - but you are right, if I past the string above info PHP it works (also with 7.4.28) but not if the string is returned from DB. It's then somehow "{"a": "M�ller", "b": "bar"}" and json_decode() returns null.

Comment: I also tried the whole thing with MariaDB 10.3.34 - there the umlaut remains as before.

Comment: But, what [exact error message](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) are you getting? My guess is that it isn't UTF-8. The fact that `ü` gets seemingly printed as a single character suggests you're negotiating your DB connection as ISO-8859-1 or something similar.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you for pointing to json_last_error_msg(). The error message is "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded".

I checked the raw bytes delivered by MySQL to PHP compared to a local string:
local string: ü => c3 bc - which seems UTF-8;
MySQL: ü => fc - which seems ISO_8859-1 as you assumed.

Do I have to set UTF-8 in my DB connection? I have no issues with special chars and umlauts in other (non-JSON) table columns.

Comment: In deed, if I set the encoding of the DB connection using set_charset("utf8") it works.

But I'm afraid I have to check all other places where I use such chars and also the existing content of the DB if there is something to convert, if I change the encoding of the DB connection.

And I'm still confused, why MySQL will replace my \u encoding with UTF-8 at all.